# Is this a reasonable way to only include jquery plugins when they are needed?

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm creating a website for use in-house, using Laravel and some other things that I've been wanting to learn, as I was given a bit of freedom and it's more fun than WordPress etc.

I want my colleagues who are not overly web savvy to be able to create pages and include some nice functionality easily, for instance they know that adding a div with a class '.textCarousel', with p tags within it, will create a styled carousel of those p tags etc.

What I don't want to have to do (or think I don't want to have to do, it might actually be preferable to my current 'solution' - which is why I am here) is include a ton of jQuery plugins on every page if they aren't going to be used.

What I have done as a workaround (in pseudo-code here) is this:

```
if(selector.length)
    selector.each
        var defaults = { ..., script: 'path/to/plugin' },
            data = this.data(),
            opts = extend(defaults, data),
            tis  = this;

        if(!opts.script.length)
            head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
            script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = opts.script;
            head.appendChild(script);

        if(opts.script.length && !$.fn.plugin)
            script.on('load', *initplugin*)
        else
            tis.initplugin(opts)
```

Does this seem like an OK way to do things or am i creating lots of unnecessary boilerplate and should just include the available plugins as default?

Comment: caching one large js file is probably better than making several requests to files as you need them

Comment: Otherwise you can use [getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)